# Estimating where my competitor is getting most of their traffic from? Organic, PPC, or other?

Tags: seo, traffic, keywords, sem, competitors

I'm trying to figure out how/where a website gets its traffic.  How are they successful with bringing in traffic?  Via Organic, PPC, other?   What is the best approach to estimating this?

My thought is to look at their top keywords from the meta tag, plug that into google keyword analysis tool to see how much traffic is generally brought to that site, and try to estimate how much of that traffic results in clicks (perhaps by using estimated PPC performance for that keyword using traffic estimation tool by google).  What do you think about this?

But that would just cover traffic from google.  How about traffic from other sites like yahoo, bing, etc, etc..twitter, facebook, other links from other sites... how does one estimate this without spending days and days?  There has to be an app or easier way.  Any thoughts?  THanks.

Answer (score 4):

*You could try [Moz's Open Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/):*

> - Investigating the link data of a competitor to determine where they're
>     earning press/attention so you can
>     reverse engineer their marketing
>     efforts
> - Comparing link metrics between multiple sites to determine the level
>     of competition / difficulty/importance
>     of your own site in comparison

Answer (score 2):

Semrush is a tool that estimates search traffic, (both PPC and Organic) compete.com estimates total traffic and shows top referring sources (IE twitter Facebook etc.) these are just estimates but they seem to be the closest to accurate of any similar tools I've seen.