# Is it possible to get information about competitor traffic?

Tags: analytics, traffic, visitors, web-traffic, competitors

Is there a possibility to get competitor website traffic info?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com#

Comment: See: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5246/estimating-where-my-competitor-is-getting-most-of-their-traffic-from-organic-p

Answer (score 7):

Here are some services I know of where you can find traffic info:

- [Alexa ~ Stack Overflow](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com#)
- [Compete Pro ~ Stack Overflow](http://siteanalytics.compete.com/stackoverflow.com/)
- [Quantcast ~ Stack Overflow](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com)

I also like [SEMRush](http://www.semrush.com/info/stackoverflow.com) for drilling down on the specific keywords (paid or un-paid) and rankings that are driving traffic. There are also some paid services that offer competitor traffic estimates, if you can afford $10k per month then check out [comscore](http://www.comscore.com). The [following article provides an excellent summary of their methodologies](http://www.antezeta.com/blog/web-statistics-suppliers) and limits of their accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

You can find some important metrics of your competitor at [Open Site Explorer by MOZ](https://moz.com/researchtools/ose/links?site=stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. You could use [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/) to see statistics based on views by users using the [Alexa toolbar](http://www.alexa.com/toolbar). However this data is far from realistic.

Some websites use (free) public tracking facilities. You could check for a little statistics logo on the website (mostly at the bottom) or you could check the HTML source code for statistics related JavaScript. However this is mostly used on sites *you* probably don't care about.

Comment: Let me add a little nuance to Alexia. The bigger (more visitors) the website, the more realistic the data is probably going to be.

Comment: You probably mean Alexa - http://www.alexa.com/

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is... in a way :) If they have at least 1 Google product on their page (except Analytics, or they share Analytics data), you can use this <strike>[Google Adplanner](https://www.google.com/adplanner)</strike>. Google has discontinued Google Adplanner and is know as [Google Display Planner](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3056153?hl=en-GB), of which can be found within the Adwords Dashboard.

Comment: Can you give more details? I'm not sure if i know what you mean. Would this work for all sites, or only for sites with ads?

Answer (score 0):

No way! But calculating the keyword density and the position of the competitor calculating this things we can get an approximate result

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to get an idea of where their traffic comes from. Take a look at their meta keywords, if they have them, to see what keywords they may be targetting. Also get a look at the market they are trying to target.

Take a look at their backlinks, too which can also give you an idea of what keywords they are chasing after.

Tools like Alexa can help you get an idea what their market is and what keywords people are using to end up on their site. Don't stop at Alexa either, there are several others such as Quantcast that pick up totally different statistics.

You won't be able to see anything as accurate as their Google Analytics account, but you will get an idea of what they are targetting. Once you do that, go to Google Analytics to see what kind of traffic their keywords get based on their SERP for each keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are several competing websites that give you traffic estimation.
Let me add to the answer from Simon Hayter:

- Alexa (already mentioned) - [Stack Overflow](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com)
- Compete Pro (already mentioned) - [Stack Overflow](http://siteanalytics.compete.com/stackoverflow.com/)
- Quantcast (already mentioned, **and the data is confirmed!**) [Stack Overflow](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?qcLocale=en_US)
- (NEW) Similar Web - [Stack Overflow](http://www.similarweb.com/website/stackoverflow.com)